# Cannot delete record in CodeIgniter using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to delete a record in CodeIgniter but it's getting an error.

This is the model I created:

```
public function delete_by_id($id) {
    $My_Multiple_Statements_Array = array('id' => $id, 'tipe' => $tipe);
    $this->db->where($My_Multiple_Statements_Array);
    $this->db->delete($this->table);
}
```

Controller:

```
public function ajax_delete($id) {
    $this->paket->delete_by_id($id);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
```

And AJAX:

```
function delete_person(id)
{
    if (confirm('Are you sure delete this data?'))
    {
        // ajax delete data to database
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('paket/ajax_delete') ?>/" + id ,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data)
            {
                //if success reload ajax table
                $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                reload_table();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error deleting data');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Why can't it delete the record?

Comment: Its undefined `$tipe` in model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In model variable `$tipe` is undefined.

If it just a typo error than just remove from:

```
$My_Multiple_Statements_Array = array('id' => $id, 'tipe' => $tipe);
```

Should be:

```
$My_Multiple_Statements_Array = array('id' => $id);
```

If `$tipe` is your property than use like `$this->tipe`.

If you want to pass `$tipe` in ajax request than use like that:

```
$.ajax({ 
url: "<?php echo site_url('paket/ajax_delete') ?>/", 
type: "POST", 
data: "id="+id+"&tipe="+tipe,
dataType: "JSON", 
success: function (data) { 
//if success reload ajax table $('#modal_form').modal('hide'); reload_table(); 
},
```

Pass `tipe` in ajax data as you are using `id`

You can get both values in your controller by using `$_POST` like:

**Your controller:**

```
public function ajax_delete() { 
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $tipe = $_POST["tipe"];
    $this->paket->delete_by_id($id,$tipe); 
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE)); 
}
```

**Your model:**

```
public function delete_by_id($id,$tipe) { 

    $My_Multiple_Statements_Array = array('id' => $id, 'tipe' => $tipe); 
    $this->db->where($My_Multiple_Statements_Array); 
    $this->db->delete($this->table); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer
but I want to define $tipe in ajax

          url: "<?php echo site_url('paket/ajax_delete') ?>/" + id 

how to add tipe in ajax url?